# Entry point not found on OpenCV dll with Qt 5.12

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, dll

**TLDR:** Linking OpenCV with QT MingW makes application crash in Debug but not release.

I am trying to use OpenCV in a large multi OS project based on Qt. I have easily managed to build OpenCV for Mac and Linux but I am very much struggling to use it on Windows.

**Environment:**

Qt 5.12.2 MinGW

MinGW 8.1.0 64bit

OpenCV basically all versions since 4.1.0

CMake 3.19

**What I tried**

- I first tried to build OpenCV from source following his link https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows but had some issues running the application in Debug such as Entry Point not Found in opencv Library (exact error below)
- I lately used prebuilt packages from MSys2 using its pacman and tried version 4.2 to 4.5 without real success. I managed a couple of time to link the OpenCV libraries from the installation path of msys (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin) and with this path in the environment PATH I was able to launch the application using the .exe generated by Qt. However once I dragged the needed  libraries into our third party libraries folder for deployment the application can't start anymore in Debug (with Qt nor with the .exe).
- I tried in Release mode and everything works fine

Now everytime I run the application in Debug with Qt the program crash immediately without even entering the main. I have the following error when I use the .exe:

[image]

I have seen that it could be a TBB issue so I tried using a different version from MSys without success.

I tried to change the PATH variables from Qt for the Build and the Run without success.

My includes and Libs in my *.pri* are used as follow (they are all found during the build)

```
INCLUDEPATH += -I $$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/include/opencv4
DEPENDPATH += -$$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/include/opencv4

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/lib/$$OSFOLDER/$$ARCHFOLDER  -lopencv_imgproc430
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/lib/$$OSFOLDER/$$ARCHFOLDER  -lopencv_core430
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/lib/$$OSFOLDER/$$ARCHFOLDER  -lopencv_dnn430
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/lib/$$OSFOLDER/$$ARCHFOLDER  -lopencv_imgcodecs430
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../ext/OpenCV/lib/$$OSFOLDER/$$ARCHFOLDER  -lopencv_highgui430
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay so I finally managed to get it work!
As I said in my question this error happens sometimes when the TBB version is not correct so here's what I did:

- Build manually TBB with this repository: https://github.com/wjakob/tbb which contains a CMake-based build system of the official repository : https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB
- Build OpenCV with the version needed using the compilers you will use later in your application:

  - Uncheck 'BUILD_TBB', check 'WITH_TBB' and point to the previously built TBB libraries and include.
  - Add the flags you need ( OPENCV_ENABLE_ALLOCATOR_STATS=OFF for instance ) and build it.
- Finally add the libraries from 'path/to/opencv-build/bin' instead of 'path/to/opencv-build/install/bin' (maybe that's what we should always do but I wasn't sure) and it worked for me!